# Eclipse Grapic Layout: Unable to resolve drawable ... in attribute "background"

Tags: android, eclipse, background, bitmap

**Hi. I'm adding a background xml file to an Imageview but i get this error in the Eclipse Graphical layout:**

> error! Unable to resolve drawable
>   "com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.ResourceValue@1ae0c2"
>   in attribute "background" Exception
>   details are logged in Window > Show
>   View > Error Log

**When i run the widget on the device, the background is displayed in the right way, but the error in Eclipse is really annoying. The background file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/grey_back_tile"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**And here's where I use it:**

```
    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_width="286dp" android:layout_height="47dp" android:background="@drawable/widget_background_banner"/>
```

**The error log stack trace shows:**

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:
>   Binary XML file line #5: 
>   requires a valid src attribute    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:341)
>     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:779)
>     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:720)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:150)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:668)
>     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:1846)
>     at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:109)
>     at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:105)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:77)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:122)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:377)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createLegacySession(LayoutLibrary.java:394)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:276)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.partActivated(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.partBroughtToTop(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList$2.run(PartListenerList.java:87)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.fireEvent(PartListenerList.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.firePartBroughtToTop(PartListenerList.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartBroughtToTop(PartService.java:208)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.firePartBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.fireActiveEditorChanged(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.setActiveEditor(PartList.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.makeActiveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3530)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.requestActivation(WorkbenchPage.java:3077)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:279)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.requestActivation(EditorPane.java:98)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setFocus(PartPane.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.setFocus(EditorPane.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(PartStack.java:844)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(PartStack.java:827)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(PartStack.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:133)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:278)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$2.handleEvent(DefaultTabFolder.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

**Naturally the "grey_back_tile.png" is a valid resource, and it's located int the "drawable-hdpi" folder. Any clue to get rid of that error?**

Comment: have you copied your drawables to all folder hdpi, ldpi, mdpi

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to this but faced the same issue. I'm pretty certain it's an Eclipse ADT bug but to prevent the annoying errors, if you create a style and add a background item to your tiled background and refer the layout to that, as opposed to editing the background attribute on the layout, it should work and you won't get the annoying errors.

So, tiled background XML named app_background:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/space"  android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then a style, referring to it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TestBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then assign the style to the layout:

```
style="@style/TestBackground"
```